# DELETE BY MIN VALUE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table in sql:

| ID | Category | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 202101 |
| 2 | A | 202101 |
| 3 | B | 202001 |
| 4 | B | 202001 |

I want to delete the rows with Min(ID)

The expected output is:

| ID | Category | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | 202101 |
| 4 | B | 202001 |

A

Comment: What if there is exactly one row for a partcular category?

Comment: I've a previous query that find duplicates in the table, I intend to use that query as the table.

Comment: What about more than 2 rows for same Category? Do you want to really delete only the record with min value, or keep the one with max value and delete the rest?

Comment: I've managed to make sure that in the table I've only duplicated values in the category field. There isn't any possibility of having more than 2 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one removes all duplicates, irrespective of duplicate count, leaving out only the one with highest ID.

```
;with cte as
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Category order by ID desc) from YourTable
)
delete from cte where rn <> 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DELETE``:

```
delete from t
    where t.id = (select min(t2.id)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.category = t.category
                 );
```

You can use similar logic in a `SELECT` if you just want results in a query:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id > (select min(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.category = t.category
            );
```

Note:  Normally, the goal of such an operation is to *keep the most recent id* rather than *deleting the oldest*.  If that is the case, you can use a variation of the first query:

```
delete from t
    where t.id < (select max(t2.id)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.category = t.category
                 );
```